# Master PDF Editor installs correctly, but won't start

Tags: applications, appcenter

I installed Master PDF editor from [here](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/), selecting the 64 bit .deb file. I installed it through the software center, and everything seemed to have been installed correctly, except that when I try to click its icon on the Applications menu the program doesn't start, nor does it start if I try to open a file with it; Gnome System Monitor doesn't show it anywhere, either. I tried purging and reinstalling, but nothing changed.

Comment: I had the same problem using Debian Jessie. Looked through Internet hoping to find any clue but so far none has proven to be useful or even slightly close to define what might be causing the problem.

Comment: Are you on Freya or Loki?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, tried downloading the qt4 version and it still does the same. I'm in Loki. I'm guessing we have to install some sort of qt libraries, but thats how far my knowledge goes. I have no idea of how we install qt libraries on elementary.

Comment: Me the same after 2 years. I have install the 32bit version for Ubuntu, the application installed correctly but doesn't start :(

Comment: I'm STILL having this problem and I unfortunately paid for the pro version of Master PDF Editor. It did work until recently. I'm using Arch Linux. I would love to see a resolution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the dependencies so there is a library missing (you can see this in the system log):

```
gnome-session[1630]: /opt/master-pdf-editor-3/masterpdfeditor3:
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5PrintSupport.so.5:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It might be a good idea to file a bug report but for now there is a workaround (in the terminal):

```
sudo apt install libqt5printsupport5
```

Comment: The package is already install but the Master Pdf Editor still doesn't start.

Comment: Having the same problem since the last two days. Unfortunately, running `masterpdfeditor5` from the command line does not create any log entries.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was the package "libsane" missing.

After installing it, it started working on Jessie (using masterpdfeditor4 and installing "qt5-default" before masterpdfeditor4 .deb file via gdebi).